# How to distribute an application using shared library on Linux

Tags: linker, shared-libraries

My app uses library: boost, ffmpeg (avcodec, avformat,...). I want to pack my app to run on Ubuntu 14 or higher. I don't want to use static build.

I have checked on some computers which install Ubuntu. Here is results: 
Ubuntu 14.04:

```
ls -l libavcodec*
libavcodec.a
libavcodec.so -> libavcodec.so.54.35.1
libavcodec.so.54.35.1

ls -l libboost_thread*
libboost_thread.a
libboost_thread.so -> libboost_thread.so.1.54.0
libboost_thread.so.1.54.0
```

Ubuntu 16.04:

```
ls -l libavcodec*
libavcodec.a -> libavcodec-ffmpeg.a
libavcodec-ffmpeg.a
libavcodec-ffmpeg.so -> libavcodec-ffmpeg.so.56.60.100
libavcodec-ffmpeg.so.56 -> libavcodec-ffmpeg.so.56.60.100
libavcodec-ffmpeg.so.56.60.100
libavcodec.so -> libavcodec-ffmpeg.so

ls -l libboost_thread*
libboost_thread.a
libboost_thread.so -> libboost_thread.so.1.58.0
libboost_thread.so.1.58.0
```

My app

```
objdump -p  ControlStation | grep NEEDED
NEEDED               libavcodec-ffmpeg.so.56
NEEDED               libavformat-ffmpeg.so.56
NEEDED               libavutil-ffmpeg.so.54
NEEDED               libswscale-ffmpeg.so.3
NEEDED               libboost_system.so.1.58.0
NEEDED               libboost_thread.so.1.58.0
....
```

I compile on Ubuntu 16, so my app uses file libavcodec-ffmpeg.so.56 and libboost_thread.so.1.58.0. Therefore, it couldn't run on other computers.

Normally, a shared library should be

```
libName.so ---> libName.so.MAJOR
libName.so.MAJOR --> real library file
```

But ffmpeg has many versions, boost library doesn't have symbolic file libboost_thread.so.1


Could anyone help me about this problem ? Thank you !